# Изменение сеттера через рефлексию

Tags: c#

Как сделать аналог такого свойства через рефлексию?

```
private string _myProperty1;

public string MyProperty1 
{
    get => _myProperty1;
    set
    {
        _myProperty1 = value;
        Test();
    }
}
```

Текущий код падает с ошибкой: System.ArgumentException: 'method arguments are incompatible'

```
class MyClass
{
    delegate void TestDelegate(dynamic value);
        
    public MyClass()
    {
        TestDelegate testDelegate = Test;
        foreach (var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var setter = prop.GetSetMethod();
            setter.CreateDelegate(typeof(TestDelegate), testDelegate);
        }
    }
        
    private void Test(dynamic value = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Works!");
    }
        
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: что должна делать строчка `setter.CreateDelegate(typeof(TestDelegate), testDelegate);`?

Comment: @Grundy насколько я понимаю, она вернет мне делегат для сеттера с типом свойства, который должен вызываться при обращении к сеттеру и в котором уже будет добавлен мой вызов Test(). Возможно я вообще двигаюсь не в том направлении, чтоб сделать подобие хука для сеттера

Comment: Не, это так не работает. Динамически подменить содержимое метода - весьма не тривиально. Поэтому лучше сразу указывать вызов какого-то делегата

Answer (score 2):

Используйте старый как мир паттерн GoF: [Proxy](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/proxy):

<sub>Библиотечный класс (read-only)</sub>

```cs
public sealed class SomeClass
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

<sub>Proxy-класс</sub>

```cs
public sealed class SomeClassProxy
{
    SomeClass inst;

    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get => inst.SomeProperty;
        set
        {
            // checking skipped

            inst.SomeProperty = value;
            
            Test();
        }
    }

    public SomeClassProxy()
    {
        inst = new SomeClass();
    }

    void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test!");
    }
}
```

<sub>Использование</sub>

```cs
void Run()
{
    var proxy = new SomeClassProxy { SomeProperty = "hello" };

    Console.WriteLine("Changing...");

    proxy.SomeProperty = "bye";
}
```

<sub>Вывод</sub>

```
Test!
Changing...
Test!
```